# Как зафиксировать нажатия на кнопки Volume Up/Down в фоне?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть метод `OnKeyDown()`, но он работает только если `Activity` запущена. В `Service` нельзя применять данный метод. Как еще можно поступить?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154118/listen-to-volume-buttons-in-background-service/11510564)